# Set size of PolarLine Chart

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

is there any way to set specific size of PolarLine Chart (not the ChartArea, the chart)

In the image it can be seen the "space reserver to I don't know what"

So there is two options, determine the size of Chart, or equalize the size of chart to the ChartArea.

```
$("#chart2").kendoChart({
                chartArea: {
                    background:"",
                    border: {
                        width: 2,
                        color: "green"
                    }  
                },
                legend:{
                    visible: false
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "polarLine",
                    style: "smooth"
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [
[0,75.07200602],[10,81.64361286],
[20,91.39178047],[30,98.75515111],
[40,99.92040115],[50,92.10607453],
[60,74.91674346],[70,50.02020242],
[80,11.87856731],[90,0.998505703]
]
                }],
                xAxis:
                {
                    startAngle: 90,
                    majorUnit: 10,

                    reverse :true,
                    majorGridLines: {
                        max: 360,
                        min: 0,
                        visible: true
                    },
                    labels:
                    {
                        visible: false,
                        margin:3,
                        template:"#: value # º"
                    }
                },
                yAxis:
                {
                    max: 100,
                    min :0,
                    majorUnit: 10,
                    labels:
                    {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}",
                    template: "#: value #"
                },
                transitions:false
            });
```

[White space problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4gyf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was creating a function that rezise chart once is calculated depending the cointainer size, in my case was:

```
function reziseChart(ParentDiv)
        {
           var clientHeight = document.getElementById(ParentDiv).clientHeight;
            var c = $("#chart2").data("kendoChart");
            c.options.chartArea.margin = - clientHeight * 0.425;
            c.refresh(); 
        }
```